# How to change members per page in BuddyPress members directory

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

In BuddyPress, it shows 20 members per members directory page. I want to list 24 members per page with a pagination and sorting must work perfectly. I tried:

`bp_has_members(bp_ajax_querystring('members').'per_page=24'))`

It works but pagination and sorting are not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an '&' for each additional argument.
Try:

```
bp_has_members(bp_ajax_querystring('members').'&per_page=24'))
```

Comment: This no longer seems to work with the current version of buddypress. @glouton's answer is working correctly with current versions.

Answer (score 3):

For those like me wondering how to do this nowadays and ending here after searching with their fav engine, the proper way is to use a filter in bp-custom.php or the functions.php of your theme.
Cf. https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/using-bp_parse_args-to-filter-buddypress-template-loops/

For the member loop it would be something like :

```
function my_bp_members_per_page( $retval ) {
    $retval['per_page'] = 24;

    return $retval;
}
add_filter( 'bp_after_has_members_parse_args', 'my_bp_members_per_page' );
```

Bonus : this will still work if you use cache like WP Rocket.
Former method doesn't work with cache and logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

To modify this file, you make a copy of it and put it into your child-theme
/your-child-theme/buddypress/members/members-loop.php